# On booting ubuntu installer from PD, it shows up a black screen with error codes

Tags: boot

I am having HP Compaq dc5800 small form factor PC with 2 GB RAM, 2.20 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo Processor, 160 GB of HDD, Intel Q33 integrated graphics and I am currently running Windows 10 Pro (32-bit), although my PC i s 64-bit supported. When I boot my PC from Ubuntu 18.04 installation media (flash drive), it opens up a screen with options like try Ubuntu without installing, install Ubuntu, check drive for errors and 2 more. But when I click any of the above two options, it displays a command prompt like black read only screen with error codes on it. I want to install Ubuntu in dual boot with Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

To load Ubuntu installation from a USB drive, you need to have UEFI enabled (that is the default for the newest computers). If you have it disabled when trying to use the Ubuntu Live media, while it'd still most likely work, you will lose functionality.

The SecureBoot option may or may not work, depending on your computer. If SecureBoot enabled failed, just change that to disabled.

If the Try Ubuntu without installing option fails to boot

Some computer's hardware may have problems with some of the Desktop drivers. You can fix this by typing e at the Try Ubuntu without installing option from the initial black screen menu. Then replace the words quiet splash with nomodeset. Then hit F10 to boot.

Comment: How to enable UEFI option on HP BIOS 1.04?

Comment: Have a look here, it might be helpful. https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c03801890